# Checksum validation failed while downloading maven dependency

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project with these dependencies -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I did a fresh (*deleted `repository` directory under `.m2`*)  **`mvn clean install`**.

One machine 1 (*mvn version - 3.3.3*), under `.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/hbase-server/1.2.2`

It successfully downloaded

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 impadmin impadmin   32265 Sep  6 19:51 hbase-server-1.2.2.pom
-rw-rw-r-- 1 impadmin impadmin      40 Sep  6 19:51 hbase-server-1.2.2.pom.sha1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 impadmin impadmin 4147025 Sep  6 19:52 hbase-server-1.2.2.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 impadmin impadmin      40 Sep  6 19:52 hbase-server-1.2.2.jar.sha1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 impadmin impadmin 7492332 Sep  6 19:53 hbase-server-1.2.2-tests.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 impadmin impadmin      40 Sep  6 19:53 hbase-server-1.2.2-tests.jar.sha1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 impadmin impadmin     291 Sep  7 12:07 _remote.repositories
```

On machine 2 (*mvn version - 3.0.4*), under same directory

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   32265 Sep  7 14:02 hbase-server-1.2.2.pom
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      40 Sep  7 14:02 hbase-server-1.2.2.pom.sha1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4147025 Sep  7 14:05 hbase-server-1.2.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      40 Sep  7 14:05 hbase-server-1.2.2.jar.sha1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   26400 Sep  7 14:26 hbase-server-1.2.2-tests.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     393 Sep  7 14:26 _maven.repositories
```

**You see `hbase-server-1.2.2-tests.jar.sha1` is missing and  `hbase-server-1.2.2-tests.jar` is corrupted (40 KB)**

Jenkins logs:

> Downloading: http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/org/apache/hbase/hbase-server/1.2.2/hbase-server-1.2.2-tests.jar
>
> [WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected b40b13063ee56ba3b783645444545d520ca40764 but is cd3be44d9c4c4b20a12f70acc17a58e8141d7bed for http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/org/apache/hbase/hbase-server/1.2.2/hbase-server-1.2.2-tests.jar
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project kundera-hbase-v2: Compilation failure
>
> **[ERROR] error: error reading /root/.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/hbase-server/1.2.2/hbase-server-1.2.2-tests.jar; error in opening zip file**

---

Also tried with `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2` repository. Result is same.

Comment: How many times did you try? Do it a few times.

Comment: @vz0 I tried 4-5 times.

Comment: Download the JAR manually with a web browser or with wget from the command line and check the signature manually with sha1sum.

Comment: I've just done it myself, the file checks out fine. There is something wrong with your internet connection. I really doubt it is something wrong with Maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just manually downloaded the JAR file and the checksum is the correct one. There is a problem with your internet connection. Probably a broken cable, interface, router, etc., or a firewall/anti-virus software going bananas.

Comment: I downloaded other hundreds of dependencies. I am getting the issue with this particular jar only. Might be a bottleneck from the server where the files are hosted.

Comment: As per your comment, I downloaded jar manually using `wget` and checked checksum. It's the same. Although downloading failed at 1st time.